# Ubuntu 16.04 Server, Log to Database instead of default logs

Tags: server, log

I'm currently working with a group that runs a small gaming network, they have recently had a few 'issues' with their administrators not seeing eye to eye so I was called in to secure their systems and take over administration.

We currently run Ubuntu 14.04 though upgrading to 16.04 is planned during next scheduled maintenance.

The managers would like more secure command logging (instead of standard `.bash_history` and `auth.log`) as anyone with the power to run commands also has the power to modify the relevant log files.

I suggested using MySQL to store the logs as people can be granted permission to view but not edit and only selected users can make changes.

So to the point, is there currently a package that would store the Date, Time, Username and command to an SQL Database (including sudo commands) for added security?

If not, is there an other suggestions on how I may lock write access to `.bash_history` for the user it pertains to and have root write the logs instead?

I have had a quick look around on google and the search terms keep returning MySQL logging files, but i will continue to look.

Comment: Do you want MySQL, or is any solution (like logstash/elasticsearch) acceptable?

Comment: We already have Mysql running on the server so for simplicity sake it would be nice to incorporate, but we are flexible, security is key

Comment: The reason I ask is that MySQL is sort of... bad... at handling large amounts of data that needs to be easily searchable. I mean, sure, you can use it, but you'd essentially have  three columns: `id`, `log_level`, and `entry`. Which, depending on what your network is and what you're trying, might make search and audit trails even harder than it currently is.

Comment: Your users have permissions to edit `auth.log`? O.o If they have unfettered root access, they can undo any action you take. If not, then provide them fine-grained, as-needed sudo privileges.

Comment: ok a little network info, its a games server network with about 5 admins, all the servers we run dont require any sudo to access and use, so its all low level and these minecraft and steam game servers have there own internal logging. we just want to log SSH commands from each user as they hit the Return key. most commands are not typed in shell so the audit process should mostly be log in/logout and it would be simple to find a user typing a command that they shouldn't

Comment: @muru, no they no longer have un vetted root access, only myself and server owner have root access now, but auth.log only records sudo command attempts and most staff cannot sudo

Comment: @L.H. in that case, uses something like `auditd` http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86003/70524, then send to syslog: http://serverfault.com/questions/202044/sending-audit-logs-to-syslog-server, then use rsyslog to dump to MySQL: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ommysql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to other solutions, I'd advise using specialized logging software instead of MySQL. The reasoning for this is that MySQL has been known to be problematic for log storage, especially without any sort of preprocessing. In other words, if you're just dumping raw log entries into a MySQL table, you're likely going to end up with very few columns: `id`, `timestamp`, `log_level`, and `log_entry` (or any sub-combination of these). This, as a result, makes searching very hard, as you'll have to either wait a long time to work through *all* of your log entries plus the memory overhead of indexing might be unacceptable for your network. Sure, you could design a custom schema that is slightly more usable and efficient in data storage and retrieval, but this may require maintenance if any part of the logging chain changes operation or if you want to log data you weren't logging before.

Similarly, if you're using MySQL for user/gamedata/whatever storage, doing such a thing would add much more overhead to the database. Thereby, this could slow down your entire system's infrastructure (depending on system load, I would recommend on doing some testing).

***Anyways...***

If you do want to go down the rabbit-hole of centralized logging and log management, I would suggest something like Logstash combined with Elasticsearch for query information. You can also (if you want) throw Kibana into the mix to create something known as the full [ELK stack](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_series/centralized-logging-with-elk-stack-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-on-ubuntu-14-04). The problem with this solution, however, is that Elasticsearch is essentially a global index and requires a decent investment of development and/or operations time in order to set it up in an effective way. You will also have to set aside a *lot* of hard drive space (and possibly memory) if not a dedicated server for logging. Of course, there are a lot of alternatives to the ELK stack, and you can probably find the solution that works best for you with a bit of research. One thing to note, however, is that `logstash` requires some NoSQL database (see [supported outputs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/output-plugins.html)).

Either way, depending on whatever logging solution you choose, there are ways to integrate such log information into most logging stacks. As an example, I run a small Minecraft network using fully custom infrastructure and software. Our system is designed to log to ELK, which then provides us with searchable information regarding users, in-game commands, "high-lag" events, and similar actions. Of course, this might not be necessary, but the ability to expand in that direction may be useful for future expansion and simplicity of development and administration.

---

Either way, I've talked too much about logging without really giving an answer, so I think I should try to do that.

My current opinion (based on your comments) is that you have a few problems that need to be solved in no particular order:

- **Don't let users even go where they shouldn't.**
  Linux has *extremely* powerful access control management. You can just block users access to things they shouldn't have access to. For example, using `/etc/sudoers` to limit what commands someone can (or can't) run.
- **Giving users full `root` makes logging impossible**
  So, I'm going to let my imagination run wild here. You give your users access to `sudo` without restriction. If I, a rogue admin, were to run `sudo -s` or a similar command, I would drop into a root shell without problem. At this point, you lose a few things. First, you have no idea who is actually running that command. All you'll know is that `root` ran it. Second, a rogue admin can *very easily* disable logging to whatever backend server they please, and then run whatever command(s) they want. Sure, you'll probably be able to tell when a user became root, and *maybe* extrapolate who ran what command after that, but this is by no means reliable anymore.

However, there is still a nifty utility called [`auditd`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-auditing-system-on-centos-7) (installing and configuring is left an exercise to the reader). Basically, this utility will log and monitor commands executed by users (even those who have escalated privileges *in certain situations*). By default, this will log to a flat file, but you can then take this and move it anywhere you want. For example, [`logstash` can record audit logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/609192/how-to-parse-audit-log-using-logstash), which you can then forward to wherever (something like [MongoDB](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04) might be good if you don't want to run an ELK stack). Still, this setup is vulnerable to rogue admins disabling logging.

Really, though, there are *hundreds* of ways to accomplish this using all sorts of technologies, but there won't be an existing technology you can just drop in and expect to work perfectly. You will need to do some research and experimentation into the platforms that exist, and choose whichever fits your price point, development capability, infrastructure resources, and similar.

---

If you *really* want to use MySQL, I would go with what Muru's comment states. Essentially, you can set up `auditd` and have `rsyslog` [pull data from `auditd`](https://serverfault.com/questions/202044/sending-audit-logs-to-syslog-server) and dump it into MySQL through the [ommysql](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ommysql.html) project, which will provide storage in a predictable fashion. Judging by the [documentation for `auditd`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Understanding_Audit_Log_Files.html), you'll be able to very easily get at least some useful fields, which will allow for a decent schema for (at least) logged commands. For example, you will be able to use `auid` to determine which user did what, `comm` or `exe` to determine what was run, the audit unique id, status results, and what was run/how it was run. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84854/56507) for an example setup.

For user logins and similar, you will need additional tables configured through `rsyslog`. In effect, each table in MySQL will only be able to hold a single action type (login, command executed, etc.). Depending on your use-case, this might very well be okay, but it does limit your ability to create a full audit trail (such features are provided by NoSQL).

You will still need a syslog server, and (ideally) a dedicated SQL server for logging.

---

Personally though, I'd go with `auditd` and the ELK stack. Easier, and room for expansion.

<sub>Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with any of the above named technologies, but I have worked with almost all of them and have my own favorites.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the details. I will be talking with the Server Managers later and il put what has been said here in English for them.